# Google doesn't list the links to my website

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console

It is more than a month that there are 24+ links listed on my Google Webmasters Tools account. However, when I use Google like this: `link:m.a.sharpasand.com` none of them appears. Also, my PageRank is zero.

I have tried different variations of with and without `www` but it doesn't work.

My website is on a subdomain but I don't think that it is a factor because I have forwarded the main domain with moved permanently. Its address is: `m.a.sharpasand.com`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google `link:` command is not accurate. It only returns a sampling of your backlinks (not only important backlinks either) and it's not up to date at all.

Just take into account the number of links in Google Webmaster Tools.

Read [this article](http://www.seomoz.org/blog/google-link-command-busting-the-myths) on SEOmoz to understand.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm still confused about the pagerank is it accurate to check pagerank in `prchecker.info`?

Comment: Focus on your visitors instead of PageRank.